# Creating Root and Server certificates via openssl to enable https on web server shows Not Secure on Chrome Browser – so HTTPS is not working

Tags: windows, openssl

We have a web service application in which we perform the following procedure to generate certificates:

1.Create a file named openssl.ini in the folder with the following content:

```
# OpenSSL configuration file.
#----Begin----
# Establish working directory.
dir                            = .

[ ca ]
default_ca                     = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
serial                         = $dir/serial
database                       = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir                  = $dir/newcerts
certificate                    = $dir/cacert.pem
private_key                    = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days                   = 3650
default_md                     = md5
preserve                       = no
email_in_dn                    = no
nameopt                        = default_ca
certopt                        = default_ca
policy                         = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName                    = match
stateOrProvinceName            = match
organizationName               = match
organizationalUnitName         = optional
commonName                     = supplied
emailAddress                   = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                   = 1024 # Size of keys
default_keyfile                = key.pem # name of generated keys
default_md                     = md5 # message digest algorithm
string_mask                    = nombstr # permitted characters
distinguished_name             = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name Prompt string
#---------------------- ----------------------------------
0.organizationName             = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName         = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress                   = Email Address
emailAddress_max               = 40
localityName                   = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName            = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName                    = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min                = 2
countryName_max                = 2
commonName                     = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max                 = 64
# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name Value
#------------------------------ ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default     = XYZ Corp
countryName_default            = US
stateOrProvinceName_default    = CA
localityName_default           = San Francisco
emailAddress_default           = support@xyz.com
organizationalUnitName_default = Business Division
commonName_default             = ServerSystem1

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints               = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier           = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier         = keyid:always,issuer:always
keyUsage                       = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement, keyCertSign

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement, keyCertSign
#----End----
```

2.Run the following Openssl commands to generate the RootCA and Server certificate

```
md ServerCert
cd ServerCert
md newcerts private
copy ..\openssl.ini ServerCert

echo 01 > serial
copy /y nul index.txt

openssl genrsa -out private/cakey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -key private/cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650 -config ./openssl.ini
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -out ServerCA.crt

openssl req -new -nodes -out req.pem -extensions v3_req -config ./openssl.ini

openssl ca -out cert.pem -extensions v3_req -config ./openssl.ini -infiles req.pem

move cert.pem tmp.pem
openssl x509 -in tmp.pem -out cert.pem

openssl rsa -in key.pem -inform PEM -out ServerKey.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform PEM -out ServerCert.der -outform DER
```

At the end of the process, the 3 files that are used later are:

1. ServerCA.crt -> Used on Windows to trust the webserver application
2. ServerKey.der -> Key used by the webserver
3. ServerCert.der -> Certificate used by the webserver application

The web server application requires the DER files to send the certificates. But in the browser, upon running the web-service application, the browser shows “Not Secure” warning.

[image]

Upon clicking on the “Not Secure” warning, the following message is displayed.

[image]

However upon clicking on the Certificate and navigating to the tab “certification path”, the message says “This certificate is OK”.

[image]

This message is the same for Root Certificate and Server Certificate.
How to change the procedure to generate the certificates or modify the .ini file, so that the web-server application is trusted by the Browser?

**Question Update:**

To install the certificate in the Windows Trust store, i followed the following steps:

1. Typed "**mmc**" from command prompt(administrator)
2. Clicked on "**File**" -> "**Add/Remove snap-in...**"
3. Clicked on "**Certificate**" -> "**Add**" -> "**Computer Account**" -> "**Next**" -> "**Finish**"
4. Clicked on "**Certificates**" -> "**Trusted Root Certification Authorities**" -> "**Certificates**"
5. Right clicked on "**Certificates**"
6. Clicked on "**All tasks**" -> "**import**" -> "**Next**" -> "**Browse**" -> **Selected the CRT file**

Comment: Did you install the certificate in Windows trust store?

Comment: Yes. Let me update the procedure in the question.

Comment: Also you have to use sha2 as digest algorithm, chrome complains for weaker algos

Comment: @Pras In which command should i make this change?

Comment: In your unit file you seem to have md5, you can change it to sha256

Comment: I have changed te message digest default_md to sha256, the browser is still showing "Not Secure" :(

Comment: Can you show your certificate using this command, openssl x509 -in ServerCert.der -text -inform der

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204015/discussion-between-ganesh-kamath-code-frenzy-and-pras).